# How can Form's length be extended?

Tags: vba, ms-access, autoresize

I'm creating a Form in which I'm summarizing, by adding a fixed set of KPIs (Label + Field), a varying number of files that are loaded, in the same process, into their respective tables. Due to the uncertainty about the total number of files cannot set the form's size. 
I've found that after 10 files the form length is reached

I'm getting

> Error "2100"

and thererefore no more sets of KPIs can be added. Questions are:

- is there any way of extending the length of the form? I've tried with **".AutoResize"** but didn't work.
- can **Pages** be added to a **form**?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Comment: You can changed the `Height` property.  But what happens when the form is too big for the screen?

Comment: I would add them to a frame with a vertical scroll bar maybe

Comment: @Nathan_Sav My point exactly.  I wanted to provide the simple solution and point out its flaws.

Comment: @BrianMStafford My respone was to the question, not your response, just in case you thought that :)

Comment: As it's in Access why not use a subform?

Comment: What do you mean by 'respective tables' - why are there multiple tables for same type of data?

Comment: Can use a Tab Control to organize other controls.

Comment: @AlvaroEstebanMuñoz If your form is bigger than the screen, how will you be able to see all the data?  So you need to provide scrolling somehow.  As suggested by Nathan_Sav, a frame control might be one option if you also add a vertical scrollbar control.

Comment: Thanks @Brian, but Height has also a limit and I overflow it!!!

Comment: Thanks @Nathan. What do you mean by "frame withvertical scroll bar" a Tab Control? I'd love doing so!!

Comment: Thanks @June7. I meant is that load each ".CSV" in a table, and for each one of then I extract some KPI.

I've thought of using Tab Control, but decided not to do since is more complicated to later export them to ".PDF" which is also a requirement. 
Maybe would be my only way out

Comment: @AlvaroEstebanMuñoz Make the form height smaller and add scrolling.

Comment: Absolutely @Brian. I don't know such a control. Which one is that control. It's just what I need. Sorry If it is so obvious, but it is my first project with Access

Comment: @Brian How do you add scrollin?

Comment: @Brian, I've just seen is a form's property but even having the scrolls bars, it has an end that cannot be overcome (or I don't know how to do so

Comment: @AlvaroEstebanMuñoz do some googling on it.  This isnt a code writing service, you've posted no code to review, so cant begin to comment on it.  Google "Frame Control" "Scroll Bars" in VBA.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan_Sav I'll do and I'll be back with results for everybody's benefits. BTW I don't need any code writing service just a candle to follow as you've already has given me, and you're no forced to answer. No hard feelings, don't get me wrong.

Comment: Export report not form to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the job got done! Certainly it was easier than I was trying to.

Just creating a Tab Control (as suggested, thanks June7)  and then, and with the proper rational, creating each of my "KPI's"  using the "CreateControl"'s param "Parent"; being it the name of the Tab where the KPI must be displayed.

```
Set ctlctrl = CreateControl("Resumen", acTextBox, , pagina, , , Y)
```

Wher "pagina" is the name of the Tab